# Determine cause of exception

Tags: python, exception

In this example

```py
try:
    raise ValueError
except ValueError as e:
    raise IndexError from e
```

The traceback notes

```
...
ValueError:

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

IndexError
...
```

If I were to catch the `IndexError`, how would I inspect the traceback to discover that it was caused by a `ValueError`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [PEP 3134](https://peps.python.org/pep-3134/#explicit-exception-chaining), `raise ... from` sets the `__cause__` attribute in the exception. You can access that:

```
try:
    try:
        raise ValueError
    except ValueError as e:
        raise IndexError from e
except IndexError as ee:
    print(type(ee.__cause__))
```

Result:

```
<class 'ValueError'>
```